# Warning "format not a string literal and no format arguments" not appearing on latest gcc version

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning, linux-distro

In my code I use the following line to print a `char readbuffer[1];` array (char array with size 1):

```
printf(readbuffer);
```

This compiles and works without an issue on my pc (Arch Linux, gcc version `7.3.1+20180406-1`). However, when I submitted my assignment containing this code to my instructor, he in fact got a compiler warning compiling my code:

```
shell.c:89:20: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
         printf(readbuffer);
```

He is using the gcc/clang version from 16.04 LTS release. We both used the same compiler flags.

Why is this? Is this suddenly not an issue anymore in the new `gcc` version? If so, why not?

Just a note: I don't want to know how to solve this issue, but just want to know why the warning is inconsistent over gcc versions.

Comment: If you just want to print a single character, use `putchar`. No need to set up a buffer and NUL-terminate it (which you didn't do, leading to Undefined Behaviour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not caused by a difference in GCC versions. Rather, [Ubuntu has modified GCC to enable `-Wformat -Wformat-security` by default](https://anonscm.debian.org/viewvc/gcccvs/branches/sid/gcc-7/debian/patches/gcc-default-format-security.diff?revision=10175&view=markup). If you pass those options on Arch Linux, you should see the same behaviour there.

Comment: This does actually make sense to me. I already thought it would be something like this, as there was never any real security issue.

Comment: Since the only valid format argument here is the empty string and the compiler is allowed to assume Undefined Behaviour doesn't happen, I suppose it would be within its rights to just eliminate the call to `printf`. But I'd be surprised if it bothers to do that test --it's not a very likely optimisation-- and if it doesn't do the test, it won't suppress the warning either.

Comment: And there absolutely is a security issue, since you have no idea what follows that array in memory, and printf will continue to read until it finds a NUL. (Also, consider the possibility that the single character is a `%`.)

Comment: @rici In other words, there is a security issue if the format string is not terminated by a null character. That is true, but not what that warning is designed to warn about. There is a separate warning for that ("warning: unterminated format string") when it gets detected at compile time. And I agree that a special case check for array length 1 doesn't make sense, but a general check that checks arrays of all lengths to see if they might possibly contain `%` characters does potentially make sense. But admittedly still less likely than what I put in my disclaimer.

Comment: @rici Regardless, I've now been able to confirm that this isn't caused by a difference in GCC versions after all.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to know how to solve this issue ...

Yes, you really *do!*

Unless your `char[1]` variable *always* contains `\0`, what you are doing is unsafe. And. if it *does* contain that, what you are doing is nothing :-)

The correct way to do what you're trying to do is, assuming a need for `printf`:

```
printf("%.1s", readbuffer);
```

This will ensure you don't try to read past that single character. Of course, if you *know* that there will always be a character, just use:

```
putchar(*readbuffer);
```

---

In terms as to why different `gcc` versions report differently, that can be put down to simple improvement over time. It's the same reason why, for example, `gcc` will complain about mismatch between number of format specifiers and number of arguments in something like:

```
printf ("%s %d\n", "hello");
```

whereas some other implementations may not.

Specifically, while the standard mandates what *must* be reported as a diagnostic, it does not otherwise limit what implementations *may* report as a diagnostic beyond that.

Later versions of a compiler may add or remove these optional diagnostics, or change how they decide to report on them.

Comment: The reason that I included the line `I don't want to know how to solve this issue ...` was because there are already plenty StackOverflow pages explaining that. The reason of the question was to find out why gcc had chosen to ommit that specific compiler warning in this newer/arch gcc version.